# Is “the most amount of {countable things}” ever an acceptable replacement for “the greatest amount of {countable things}”?

Tags: uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns, quantifiers, style-manuals

[A recent BBC article](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-us-canada-49101874) reads in part,

> Yellowstone officials say bison can run up to 30mph (50km/h) and are the animal responsible for the most amount of injuries within the park.

The phrase “the most amount of injuries” is like nails on a chalkboard to me. “Injury” is a count noun, so I feel it should be, “the greatest number of injuries.” Several grammar web sites agree.

Is there any national or regional variation that would make the BBC's sentence grammatical? (I am asking about prescription, not description. Is this an acceptable sentence in any standard variety of English?)

Comment: Online news sites feel they have to write stories so fast that they forget that sub-editors still have a role which takes a little bit of time.

Comment: The problem is that *most amount* is correct—just not with something countable. With something countable, it should be *the greatest* ***number*** (or an equivalent count word). In short, it's **most amount** or **greatest number**. You can't mix the two words. So, you're actually asking a confusing question. It's not clear *which* of the two problems you're actually concerned with.

Comment: The while thing makes me cringe. ;-) The OED has a 1801 example of “amount”, “A number of little birds, to the amount I believe of twelve or fourteen.” And 1893 and example of “any amount of”, “I have any amount of letters for you” (from Shaw!). Those are marginal enough to make me wonder if the sentence could be grammatical in a different standard dialect of English from mine.

Comment: @adam.baker Nah. The BBC website is wrote by illegitimates these days. ;-)

Comment: Cf. today's jewel: “they walked less steps” http://www.bbc.com/future/story/20190723-10000-steps-a-day-the-right-amount

Answer (score 1):

***[the most amount](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the%20most%20amount&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20most%20amount%3B%2Cc0)*** appears to have become sort of idiomatic expression in recent decades.

From [The Book That Real Estate Agents Don't Want You to Read!](https://books.google.it/books?id=kBWKOXPM3J4C&pg=PA59&dq=%22the%20most%20amount%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj8z7f1rM7jAhUGr6QKHXoIAO4Q6AEITTAH#v=onepage&q=%22the%20most%20amount%22&f=false)

> You need to get the most amount of potential buyers looking at your property within the shortest amount of time, and that is the only way to guarantee you can make that second trip to the hardware store –

From [How to Shake the Money Tree](https://books.google.it/books?id=_BFzBgAAQBAJ&pg=PT36&dq=%22the%20most%20amount%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwib-fq8rc7jAhXAwsQBHcNgDRs4FBDoAQhTMAg#v=onepage&q=%22the%20most%20amount%22&f=false) 
By Joe French

> I always use my money sparingly, so that I can get the most amount of items, for the least amount of money.

Comment: Huh, that's really interesting. I kind of want to research what's caused that now.

Comment: One of my sons does it as well—and he's quite resistant to correction! I've edited the question to clarify: I'm trying to find out if this is possible in any standard usage.

Comment: @adam baker Defining 'standard usage' involves at best arbitrary decisions. It's not always as clear cut as classifying John's register above as sarco-whimsical. But I'm surprised that the editors at the BBC let this through (or that they could be bypassed).

Comment: But does it take plural concord or singular for purposes of verb agreement with subjects headed by that? :)  More seriously, *amount* has never accepted plural concord, which may be part of the disconnect people have with this strange concoction. The first hit in your graph, which by the way is super startling, readd: “this is the point where **the MOST amount** of micro-tears ***start*** [! –tchrist] to occur”. This is pretty bizarre to imagine a parse that allows *amount* to be plural here. It’s acting like *lots of* and *a lot of*, with no number of its own now.

Comment: One of the examples your link gives is from an article also containing 'Please return your parking pass when you check-out.' Another, '... try and get 4-5 of my opponents pawns in a queue ...'. Another, 'Most people wouldn’t have guessed he would be the most richest person because he have donated billions ... he is the America’s most beloved investor.' Sources should be investigated when determining acceptability.